# CakePHP - How to return string (like JSON) from controller action to Ajax request

Tags: jquery, ajax, cakephp

So I have my JavaScript making an Ajax call to `/my_controller/ajax_action` but then in the controller I don't know what to do to output something back to the JavaScript.

I am getting errors because there is no view for `MyController::ajaxAction()` but obviously there is no view for it, so what do I do?

Comment: google: http://www.sanisoft.com/blog/2010/10/25/cakephp-sending-json-data-in-response/

Comment: What if the response isn't JSON? I would like a solution that doesn't just return JSON strings, but anything.

Comment: well, that is not what the title of the question says ^^

Comment: You should always return JSON if you ask for JSON (via .json extension) for example. What else would it be? You can pass pretty much anything with JSON. See [this article](http://www.dereuromark.de/2014/01/09/ajax-and-cakephp/) on details how to achieve that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

do this, have your variables you want to output in an array let's say `$data`, then pass that array to the view using the `$this->set('data', $data);` method, then create a view `/General/SerializeJson.ctp`. In that view file, put `<?PHP echo json_encode($data); ?>` after that you can use `$this->render('/General/SerializeJson');` and it should output the json.

General code...

**/Controllers/MyController.php**

```
public class MyController extends AppController
{
    public function ajaxAction()
    {
        $data = Array(
            "name" => "Saad Imran",
            "age" => 19
        );
        $this->set('data', $data);
        $this->render('/General/SerializeJson/');
    }
}
```

**/Views/General/SerializeJson.ctp**

```
<?PHP echo json_encode($data); ?>
```

Answer (score 4):

Easiest way I found was to disable the automatic rendering:

```
function ajax_action($data = null) {
    if($this->RequestHandler->isAjax()) {
        $this->autoRender = false;
        //process my data and return it
        return $data;
    } else {    
        $this->Session->setFlash(__('Not an AJAX Query', true));
        $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 3):

try this:

within your `view` folder for the corresponding `controller`(my_controller) make a folder named `json` and place a file named `index.ctp` and within that ctp file write this code:

```
<?php echo json_encode($yourVariableNameReturnedFromController); ?>
```

within your `my_controller` in `index()` wrote this code:

```
$this->set('yourVariableNameReturnedFromController', $this->YOURMODEL->find('all'));
```

within your `app_controller.php`(if not exist you have to made it) write this code

```
function beforeFilter(){
  if ($this->RequestHandler->ext == 'json') {
     Configure::write('debug', 0);
  }
}
```

Comment: here i use `index()` function for accessing the json and your url will like '/my_controller/index.json'

Answer (score 1):

AutoRender=false and Return json_encode($code)

```
public function returningJsonData($estado_id){
    $this->autoRender = false;

    return json_encode($this->ModelBla->find('first',array(
        'conditions'=>array('Bla.bla_child_id'=>$estado_id)
    )));
}
```