# jQuery .post() to refresh the pages PHP-variables without whiteout in Cake PHP

Tags: php, jquery, cakephp

I got a problem and I´m about to hurt the MVC-paradigm, so I rather ask you what to do.
I got a page which is refreshed every 10 seconds with jQuery .post()-method.

```
setInterval(function() {
    $.post("http://XYZ.de<?php echo $this->webroot."Posts/index"; ?>", { liveUpdate: "true" },
        function(response) {
            $('#loadingContent').html(response);
        }
    );
}, 10000);
```

now, where the "Posts/index" is placed I have to call the PostsController.php of Cake which allows me to reset the variables.

But it doesn´t work that way and the response is filled with all the html of a normal page-call but I only want to have the pure PHP-variables updated without html appended to that div.

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks in advance for your patience.

Comment: Page refreshing every 10 seconds... If data is changed that often, it is ok, but if it is rare occasion you should look into comet style solutions.

Comment: If I understand your question, the problem is your controller is returning a normal HTML page response when you don't want that - as your posted code just takes the response and reloads a div with it. If that is indeed the problem, then the error lies in your PHP code, not your jQuery code. You'll need to do something in the PHP code so that a full HTML page template is not being returned to your javascript.

Comment: I agree with BrianDHall. Consider adding a new page to call via AJAX that outputs something simple & parsable like JSON instead of HTML.

Comment: this post might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7124644/cakephp-how-to-return-string-like-json-from-controller-action-to-ajax-reques

Comment: Thanks for all your input. I thought that creating a json-object doesn´t fit my needs because of the controller creating multiple complex arrays which I had to restructure for the json_encode and that is an impossible amount of work ...What do you think of copying the logic to a callable php-file? well, that would hurt the dry-schema ...

Comment: Apparently you were able to use the same complex multiple array in your view? So restructuring to a usable JSON object should be possible as well?

Comment: Assuming using JSON encode. I think that I´d have to decode the JSON for the PHP variables in the view in order the PHP-foreach-loops are feeded. In that case I could better use the PHP-approach directly. So it seems the JSON-approach is work for nothing or am I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Since your array is complex multilevel and you do not want to parse JSON, the only way I see doing it would be using jQuery load().

```
setInterval(function() {
  jQuery("#RefreshMeOnPage")
    .load("http://XYZ.de<?php echo $this->webroot."Posts/index"; ?> #RefreshMeInResults > *", {liveUpdate: "true"});
  }, 10000);
```

It will make post request to server and replace contents of existing element with id `RefreshMeOnPage` with the contents of newly received element with id `RefreshMeInResults`. Docs http://api.jquery.com/load/.

NOTE: Still with refresh rate of 10 seconds, I think you should look into ajax comet solution http://cometdaily.com/maturity.html. It will receive data only when there is change, although it requires some configuration.

Comment: Thanks for your effort. After thinking about it I see my misconfiguration in the controller. It doesn´t matter if I take .post(), .load() or .ajax() with or without JSON, every approach needs certain rehashed data. I think I need a dynamically generated view sent as html with PHP variables for the certain tables with the foreach-loops which only is possible with changing the controller. The comet thing is a miracle, maybe I´ll dive into that later on ...