# CakePhp is returning HTML and BODY tags along with the json?

Tags: php, cakephp, testng, cakephp-3.2

I am trying to return plain old JSON but for some reason it is being returned like this:

```
<html>
   <body>
       {
          "token":"MTEyLSQyeSQxMCRHVS9nS2t2QVRVcGpJWjJGVERldXouWWJFTzgyZ0lCTURBZFIvdWs2RldGNm1IeWxxNGpTUw==",
          "user":{
              "id":112,
              "username":"admin",
              "firstName":"admin",
              "lastName":"admin",
           },
           "userType":{
              "id":1,
              "name":"admin"
           }
       }
   </body>
</html>
```

I am currently using CakePHP to send the response:

```
/**
 * @param $controller \App\Controller\AppController
 */
public function respond($controller) {
    $controller->response->header('Content-Type: application/json');
    $controller->response->statusCode($this->statusCode);
    $controller->response->body(json_encode($this->messages));
}
```

But I have also tried using plain PHP:

```
echo json_encode($this->messages);
die();
```

The HTML tags are not problems for my front end, they seem to be ignored by javascript. But some reason TestNG is getting the HTML tags and making the response non-parseable.

Any ideas?

Comment: what was the result of `echo json_encode($this->messages);
die();` ?

Comment: The exact same thing. @Sherif

Comment: Could you post your full controller function please?

Comment: That is the entire function, I added the function declaration though.

Comment: What version of CakePHP are you using and is there a reason why you are not using a [Json View](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/json-and-xml-views.html)?

Comment: If the tags are there even after a `die()`, then it's unlikey that they are added by CakePHP, since there won't be any further processing after the script died (besides fatal error handling). Do some debugging, start with inspecting the response body with your browsers network console, and check if there's any server processing like `mod_proxy_html` or the like.

Comment: @drmonkeyninja I am using CakePHP 3.2. I just tried using Json View instead, no luck.

Comment: try using exit() rather than die(); Exit should bypass your page parsing, which is what is adding your tags.

Comment: @VikingBlooded exit didn't work either.

Comment: Seriously??? die() and exit() are aliases. http://php.net/manual/en/function.die.php

Comment: Maybe you're using a default view that contain those tags? Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7124644/cakephp-how-to-return-string-like-json-from-controller-action-to-ajax-reques

Comment: It's just my guess but browser itself may add some tags when you're viewing your page from developer tools. Did you check your response with Fiddler or similar tool?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code to get Json Response:

```
public function respond($controller) {
    $controller->autoRender = false;
    $this->response->type('json');
    $controller->response->statusCode($this->statusCode);
    $controller->response->body(json_encode($this->messages));
}
```

Ref. [Sending correct JSON content type for CakePHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14945861/sending-correct-json-content-type-for-cakephp)